# Perform calculation on a different number of rows for each ID

Tags: encoding, average, spss

Hopefully someone smart here can help me with a description how to solve this issue. I am relative new to SPSS and want to select cases with a certain requirement.

I have a group of Identeties who has made a mathtest multiple of times. We have 1000 ID where each person (ID) has done the test 10 times. Now i wanna select how many of these persons have scored atleast 40/50 once in this test. I have managed to do so.

Here is the problem. I now wanna calculate the average score of all the tests every individual has done after the first time they scored atleast 40 points.

Example: ID nr 8 has a score of; 34,35,27,37,32,***45***,41,32,34,47
These are all in 10 different rows. So ID nr 1 appears in 10 different rows. ID 2 in 10 other rows and so on.

Like this:
ID 1 Score 34
ID 1 Score 35
ID 1 Score 27

As you can see the person has scored atleast 40p at the 6th time. And i wanna take the average henceforth from this point. So in this case (45+41+32+34+47)/6.

I also wanna know how if i consider a person "smart" or not. A smart person is someone with atleast 2 mathscores with 40p+ (dosent have to be after each other, 2 seperate occations is ok)

How do i do that?

Comment: Also, I wanna make a N_break nr to see how many times they have scored over 40p.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but to pick the right one we would need to know more about the structure of your data. For example, does each ID appear in ten rows with a different test in each, or one row with ten variables for ten tests? Please edit your original post to add a description of your data, and better yet - add an example of the data to the post.

Comment: Thx for answering ELI-k. Idk how to send it. I have edited the post. I would be so thankfull if you could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code I assume you have a variable that identifies the order of the tests for each ID:

```
sort cases by ID TestNumber.
compute ScoreOver40 = score >= 40. /* this identifies all scores g/e 40.  
compute seq=ScoreOver40.
* if seq was 1, all following seq values for same ID will also become 1.
if ID = lag(ID) and lag(seq)=1 seq=1. 
if seq=1 scoresAfterFirst40 = score.

*now to aggregate by ID.
dataset declare agg.
aggregate /out=agg /break=ID /meanAfterFirst40=mean(scoresAfterFirst40) 
     /NumScores40P = sum(ScoreOver40).
```

In the new dataset called `agg` you should find for every ID the mean of scores after the first score of 40 or more, and the count of scores of 40 or more in all the 10 tests.

**EDIT:**
Now you can use the aggregated data for further analysis. For example, you can determine which IDs had two or more high (40+) scores:

```
dataset activate agg.
compute GoodAtMaths = (NumScores40P >= 2).
exe.
```

Comment: Appreciate your time. Idk if i was unclear, but first i have to determine how many are considered "good at maths" which is either 1 or 0 (1 = good at maths, and 0 = not good at math). So i wanna know how many werent considered good first but became "good" after doing these tests. 
If a person has atleast 2 tests with 40+ points they are "good at math". How do create that N_break nr to it. Which is the first step i have to do before i take the average.

Comment: Hope I understand you right - see my addition to the answer

Comment: I am new to SPSS so i have sometimes a hard time understand what some stuff means. How do i sequence the all scores with above 40p for every ID. Eventhough i try your method i get matchmaked 1,2,3...10 for every ID (even if they dont have 40p). I only want 40p scores. If i use N_break i get 10 for every ID. Becuase i cant analyse how many 40p everyperson has. Could you try explain more thouruly and simplier terms since i am VERY new too this.

Comment: I corrected a typing mistake in the code, please try again. some explanation: variable `ScoreOver40` gets value 1 for every score over 40 (value 0 for every score lower than 40). In the aggregation variable `NumScores40P` is the sum of `ScoreOver40` for every ID, so it is actually the number of scores that were over 40 for that ID. So yes - I am still aggregating 10 rows and the N_break is always 10 - but the number of high scores is in variable `NumScores40P`.

Comment: So I have the variable for 40p or more . What is supposed to be the "break variable" and what is supposed to be the "summaries of variable" in the aggerate function?. When i only put 40p variable as the "break variable" it only counts how many 1s and 0s there are rows and it doesent count differently for each ID nr

Comment: The break variable is the ID, meaning the aggregation is of values for each ID. The aggregation calculates `meanAfterFirst40` as the mean of `scoresAfterFirst40` for each ID - which are all the scores of that ID since the first score of 40 or over (calculated in the original dataset).

Comment: Apologizing that i keep asking. So i got you right on the first one. Make a variable that shows 1 for score over 40 and 0 for under 40p. This i manage to do. 

Here is where i strugle which you explain which i unfortanely i dont get: "* seq will receive value 1 for all cases of an ID following the first score g/e 40 .
if (ID = lag(ID) or $casenum = 1) and (ScoreOver40 = 1 or lag(seq)=1) seq=1. 
if seq=1 scoresAfterFirst40 = score." What method do i use to get this, and in what do i put in what "box"

Comment: OK I edited the code to make it simpler (and also corrected a mistake) - first I give `seq` the value 1 only when the score is g/e to 40. Then, for every line, if it is the same ID as the previous line and the previous `seq` was 1, this `seq` will also be 1.

Comment: I dont understand what "seq" is. What kind of method is that. Where do i find that in the menu?

Comment: That's just a new varible, I chose the name `seq` as short for `sequence`.

Comment: Are you working with the menus?? You should open a new syntax window and paste the code from my answer to there. Then you can run the code (select it with the mouse and click the RUN button above).

Comment: When i run it it says "execution of this command stops" But i have another way to do it which you might be able to help. Every ID has a "primaryfirst" which is 1 for every ID on their first mathtest try. Lets say i have ID nr 1,5,7 and nr 9 have a first try with a score above 40. I have done select cases and coded following: Primaryfirst = 1 & Score  ≥ 40. Now only a couple get selected and only their first try. How do i remove the rest of the IDs (all their math tests) if they dont have 40p on their first try, while i keep the other scores with primaryfirst = 1 and 40p
Appericate your time

Comment: Is there anyway i can talk to someone on discord about this? Is there any SPSS group there?

Comment: There are spss groups around, but you'll probably get answers in syntax everywhere, because that's just the right way to do this... You need to learn how to debug syntax - when you got an error message, it didn't just say ""execution of this command stops", there is more information about the error both in the output window and in the syntax window you are told wich command was the problem (in which line it is in the syntax) - If you can't figure out what the problem is, you can start a new question, post the code and the error message, and we'll help you solve it.